# Помогите разобраться с передаваемым типом в параметризированный FunctionalInterface

Tags: java, java-8

Решаю, вроде, не сложную задачу:
*Создайте функциональный интерфейс NumberGenerator, параметризованный таким образом, что принимает только наследников класса Number, имеющий метод boolean cond(T arg).
Создайте в методе public static NumberGenerator<? super Number> getGenerator() с помощью лямбда выражения реализацию NumberGenerator, которая возвращает true, если число в int эквиваленте больше 0.*
Сделал в IDe следующие решение:

```
@ 
    interface NumberGenerator<T extends Number> {
        boolean cond(T arg);
    }

public static NumberGenerator<? super Number> getGenerator() {

    NumberGenerator<  > ref = (n) -> {
            return n > 0;
    };
}
```

С Integer всё работает, с остальными типами проблема, как сделать "универсальным"? В методе getGenerator() какой тип нужно передавать в NumberGenerator<***>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static NumberGenerator<? super Number> getGenerator() {
        return n -> n.intValue() > 0;
    }
```

Comment: СПАСИБО! Даже не подумал про подобное((